# Grease pencil - Brush options unable to find in v2.91.0

Tags: grease-pencil

When I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pywbPQD9vYU), I saw these options in their draw mode viewport window:

[image: brushes option image]

However, it's not present in my `DRAW` mode window (Blender v2.91.0). Because of this I'm not able to get smooth ending point in the stroke like below:

[image: Stroke from the tutorial]

Comment: Hello Jeevan, welcome to the Blender stack exchange. In future please add a relevant screenshot of your own viewport so that we might have a better idea of how your blender UI differs from the tutorial.